# Permission from LinkedIn to edit basic Profile API

Tags: linkedin-api

How do I get w_compliance permission from LinkedIn

I am trying to implement the LinkedIn API features in this page [Profile Edit API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-edit-api?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true)

However, it says, we need w_compliance permission to make changes :-

[image]

1. Is this requirement still necessary, or is there some other way to edit basic profile ?
2. How do I apply for this permission ?

Answer (score -1):

were you able to figure this out. I have this issue too.